# Would like to have my Header and Footer begin exactly from section page

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%pagestyle

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize\itshape\bfseries\nouppercase\thepage}%\ of \pageref{LastPage}} 

\makeatletter

\makeatother

\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark}

 %\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize\itshape\ampmtime}

\setlength{\headheight}{12.0pt}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\cleardoublepage

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}% maybe with \MakeUppercase

\printnomenclature

\cleardoublepage

\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}

\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage

\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}

\listoftables

\begin{abstract}
We propose an improved approach to illustrate...
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

\section{Lecture 1}

\section{Lecture 2}

\section{Lecture 3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%pagestyle
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}   
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize\itshape\bfseries\nouppercase\thepage}%\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
 %\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize\itshape\ampmtime}
\setlength{\headheight}{12.0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   %% <---- put this here
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\begin{abstract}
We propose an improved approach to illustrate...
\end{abstract}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

As per the comments, you can do this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%pagestyle
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize\itshape\bfseries\nouppercase\thepage}%\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
 %\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize\itshape\ampmtime}
\setlength{\headheight}{12.0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}   %% <---- put this here
\pagenumbering{roman}   %%<---- put this
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\begin{abstract}
We propose an improved approach to illustrate...
\end{abstract}
\clearpage               %%<---- put this
\pagenumbering{arabic}   %%<---- put this
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can delete the \cleardoublepages it is not necessary. I wish the header and footer horizontal lines and left/right marks start after list of tables/figures, abstract and nomenclature. Thanks.

Comment: @EboMensah I have updated the answer. Is it what you want?

Comment: One last thing. Is it possible that I could see page numbers (i.e. page i) on the previous page before page 1? Thank you.

Comment: @EboMensah Answer updated.